# Dar um icon a um topico no xenforum

Tags: css

Boa tarde!

Eu gostava de colocar uma imagem, no quadrado representado na imagem abaixo, já tentei de varais formas (`.node_ID > div > span`, por exemplo) mas não consegui.

Alguem me pode ajudar?
Grato

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<div class="nodeInfo linkNodeInfo">
<span class="nodeIcon"></span>

<div class="nodeText">
    <h3 class="nodeTitle"><a href="index.php?link-forums/fm-torneios-online.369/" data-description-x="#nodeDescription-369">FM Torneios Online</a></h3>
    <blockquote class="nodeDescription muted baseHtml" id="nodeDescription-369"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Q2bjzmU.png"> Um parceiro de torneios que promete trazer uma multidão para disputar as nossas competições de Football Manager!</blockquote>
</div>
```

Comment: Cara edite sua pergunta e coloque o CSS também.Outra coisa, no seu código HTML não existe nenhum elemento com a class="node_ID"...

Comment: o id é o 369...

Comment: Sem o código html e css fica complicado, sem imagem só piora

Comment: sim, tem razao guilherme.
A div é a "nodeInfo linkNodeInfo"

O codigo do index é este: https://pastebin.com/vKLNLV1w